# Fix size materialize carousel

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am trying to increase the carousel size, but the images are getting cut from the bottom and I get an extra empty space from above.

So how could I lift the images up a little bit, or maybe just cut the empty space out from above? (Using css)

Here's the code:

```
const $ = window.$;
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            numVisible: 5,
            dist: -100,
            padding: -100,
            indicators: true
        });
      });

<div class="carousel">
<a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="img/1.jpg" /></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="img/2.jpg" /></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="img/1.jpg" /></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="img/1.jpg" /></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="img/1.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

That's how I make it bigger:

```
.carousel .carousel-item {
width:500px !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your live code?

Comment: Bootstrap carousel: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/ Hope it will helps you